# Angular JS filter is updating my underlying model and affect other template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, model

I am struggling to get this to work, I consulted Angular Doc, and found that filter doesn't work very well with object, and I have got an array of object which require filtering to display on the DOM

```
[{
  name: "Hello.World", 
  count: 20
}, 
{
  name: "fruit.apple", 
  count 15
}]
```

The filter will iterate through the array above and remove the number of node according to the showLevel Param and usually there would be 100-1000 objects in that array.

```
<div ng-repeat="ctx in modal.context | showCategoryLevelForObject :0 | unique: 'name'></div>
...
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    item = { //dereference $scope.items
                        name: items[i].name,
                        count: items[i].count
                    }

                    //to filter chidrenOf
                    if (childrenOf != null && angular.isString(childrenOf) && item.name.indexOf(childrenOf) == -1) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    switch (showLevel) {
                        case 0:
                            item.name = keepCurrentNode(item.name);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            item.name = keepCurrentNode(removeNodes(item.name, 1));
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            item.name = keepCurrentNode(removeNodes(item.name, 2));
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            item.name = keepCurrentNode(removeNodes(item.name, 3));
                            break;
                        default:
                            item.name = item.name;
                            break;
                    }
                    if (item.name.length > 0) {
                        newItems.push(item);
                    }
                  }
                items = newItems;
            }
            return items;
```

the result that i want is if showLevel = 0 `[{name: "Hello" : count: 20}...]`

the result that i want is if showLevel = 1 `[{name: "World" : count: 20}...]`

It working, but this bit is causing Infinite $digest Loop Error as model changed

```
item = { 
//dereference $scope.items
  name: items[i].name,
  count: items[i].count
}
```

if I swap it to

```
item[name] = items[i].name
```

the error is no longer happening, but instead it is updating the underlying $scope.model

e.g. DOM: `<div class="DOM">Hello.World</div>`

Opening a modal trigger the filter. inside modal: `<div class="modal">Hello</div>`

the DOM is also updated and now its displaying "Hello", which wasn't intended `<div class="DOM">Hello</div>`

Thank you very much for reading this and any help are appreciated!

Comment: My aim is to get this to work. In the context of ASP.NET MVC a ViewModel can be used, what can i use in angular?

Comment: I highly recommend you to do not use `filter` coz they mutate your model. Much better option is to set `ng-show` on your repeated item that will hide items you don't need to display. Also it works much faster then filtering your results (it's dedicated check for items instead of reviewing whole set of results). And it will not affect any other template, bcoz it is just displaying rule instead of model affecting filtering.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this is

```
items[i].filteredName = items[i].name
```

this would still modify the object, but returns the original object avoiding infinite $digest loop and

the DOM would display `item.name`

the MODAL would display `item.filteredName`

Not sure if this is a legitimate solution or simply a hack, as in my vision filter should never modify the model,